# While loop not looping after script finishes

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have 2 while loops, the first while loop is supposed to take the scanner input and loop around. Once the script is finished for the second while loop, my code stops.

```
while (timesLooped < loopTimes) {
  while (loss < 2) {

    Thread.sleep(10);

    Random randomGenerator1 = new Random();
    Random randomGenerator2 = new Random();
    int n = randomGenerator1.nextInt(max);

    int b = randomGenerator2.nextInt(max);
    if (n == 1 && b == 1) {
      loss = loss + 2;
      System.out.println("You got snake eyes and lost!");
    } else {
      score = score + n + b;
    }
    System.out.println("You got: " + n + b);
    System.out.println("Your new score is: " + score);

  }
  timesLooped = timesLooped + 1;
}
```

Comment: There is no Scanner in this snippet

Answer (score 0):

`loss` is never reset. After it completes the inner while loop once, it never runs it again since the condition always stays `false`. You add an additional print statement to confirm this is what happens:

```java
while (timesLooped < loopTimes) {
    // Once this finishes loss remains the same
    while (loss > 2) {
        // Etc...
    }
    
    // Add a print statement so we can observe it running multiple times.
    System.out.println("Ran outer loop!");

    // You need to reset loss after running the loop
    // loss = 0;

    timesLooped = timesLooped + 1;
}
```